# How to find part of url

Tags: c#, regex

How to find url part using regexp?

Url: /text1/text2/text3-text4-text5-text6-text7/aaa/100

how I can find aaa???

Comment: See: [Regular Expression URI Validation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
var uri = new Uri(s);
return uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length-2];
```

or

```
new Uri(s).Segments.Where(x => x == "aaa");
```

or

```
new Uri(s).Segments.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, "^a+$");
```

...

Your question is fairly vague on what you *actually* want and to what end.